# MultiPointTouchArea working on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I wanted to play arround with MultiTouchAreas and copied the example

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400; height: 400
    MultiPointTouchArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        touchPoints: [
            TouchPoint { id: point1 },
            TouchPoint { id: point2 }
        ]
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 30; height: 30
        color: "green"
        x: point1.x
        y: point1.y
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 30; height: 30
        color: "yellow"
        x: point2.x
        y: point2.y
    }
}
```

from the Qt Documentation. If I run the example on my Aquaris M10 I can drag the green rectangle with the first finger. But if add te second finger nothing hapens. 
Does Ubuntu 15.04 support multi touch events?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I figured out, that you have to set

```
mouseEnabled: true
```